# Ada - Is there a way to traverse through each character of an unbounded string?

Tags: ada

I basically have a unbounded string called a for example. And a is currently storing "Hello". I want to check if the letter O is in the string. This is why I want to know if there is a way where I can check each character for a match and if there is a match.

Note: I don't want to know if the entire string is equal, I just want to know if a particular character is in the string.

Comment: It looks like you haven't browsed the part of the reference manual where unbounded strings and operations on them are declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `Ada.Unbounded_Strings.Element` ([ARM A.4.5(20)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html#p20) and [(82)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html#p82), and [ARM A.4.4(96)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-4.html#p96)):

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Ubs is
   A : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String ("hello");
begin
   for J in 1 .. Length (A) loop
      if Element (A, J) = 'o' then
         Put_Line (“'o' is in A”);
         exit;
      end if;
   end loop;
end Ubs;
```

Comment: This is needed because indexing is not an overloadable operator (unlike in, say, C++).

Comment: You may want to add an `exit` or `return` in there in case the input string is `"hello world"`.

Comment: You can also do it this way:
`if (for some x of To_String(a) => x = 'o') then
        put_line("o is in A");
 end if;`
And/or use this pattern in an expression function.

Answer (score 4):

I would use Index:

```
if Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Index (A, "O") > 0 then
```

Note that the pattern is a String, not a Character, but searching for a one-character String is the same as searching for a Character.

The real answer, though, is that you should be familiar with Annex A of the ARM, which describes the standard library, and should reference it before asking questions like this. The ARM is available at

[ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-TOC.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure str_array is
   a : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String("Hello");

begin
   for i in 1 .. Length(a) loop
      if Element(a,i) = 'A' then 
         null;
      end if;
   end loop;

end str_array;
```

(and Simon beat me to it).

The lesson (for me too!) is that Unbounded_String being a private type doesn't expose the inner details the same way as String does. A bit like the difference between a C string and a C++ std::string.

There are nice techniques for dealing with Fixed Strings that mostly avoid the need for Unbounded_String, so I rarely use the latter and I apologise for leading you astray.

Easier.

```
   if Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Count((a), "A") /= 0 then 
      null;
   end if;
```

This still applies : both String and Unbounded_String supply higher level tools. Use them...

Comment: for i in 1..L loop 
       if(A(i) = guess) then                                                                  -----This is what i have but i get an error saying "array type required in indexed component"

Comment: I don’t think `’Range` is applicable to unbounded strings?